# I need to force the event play in a video of vimeo when I decide to call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, jquery-events

I have the next code in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/roberburnday/3bj5frs2/)

If i call the function with a button onclick all work's well but if i want call the function after a jquery event (as document ready or scroll) he tries it but does not play the video. ¿Any solution?

Here the function JS:

```
var ActionsVimeo = {
  forceAutoplay: function(){
    jQuery(".forceAutoplay").each(function(){
      var player = new Vimeo.Player(jQuery(this)[0]);
      player.ready().then(function() {
        player.play().then(function () {
          alert("Chimichangas it's alive!!");
        }).catch(function (error) {
          alert("No tacos remain!!",error);
        });//.play();
      });
    });
  },
};
```

Can call the function with `ActionsVimeo.forceAutoplay();`

Comment: Browsers deliberately prevent this, when it does not happen in direct connection with a user interaction such as a click that could reasonably be interpreted as the user explicitly requesting the video to play. It is an anti doucheb** measure in that regard ;-)

Comment: Thx for the answer ;-D. I'll try another thing.